# Simple objects in higher categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

$\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}} \newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}$
In an $n$-category ($n=1,2$) [Reutter defines a simple object](https://youtu.be/s7DJuF10neg?t=1480) in the following way:

> An object $X$ is simple, if one of the following equivalent conditions hold:
>
> 1. every subobject $A\hookrightarrow X$ is either zero or an equivalence
> 2. $X$ is indecomposable under $\oplus$ (working in a semisimple category)
> 3. $\End_{\mathcal{C}}(X)=\mathbb{K}$ when $n=1$, while $\End_{\mathcal{C}}\left(\id_X\right)=\mathbb{K}$ when $n=2$. (for an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$).

I would like to understand how this definition generalises to arbitrary $n$.

1. Condition 1 is the traditional definition of a simple object in a category so that is one way to define simple objects for arbitrary $n$. However, it does not buy me much understanding of what a simple object actually is.
2. It makes sense that condition 2 also directly generalises to arbitrary $n$. This is the essence of an object being called "simple".
3. My main question concerns condition 3. By the looks of it I would expect that in an $n$-category an object $X$ is simple if
   $$ \End_{\mathcal{C}}\underset{(n-1)\ \id\text{'s}}{\underbrace{\left(\id_{\id_{\ddots_{\id_X}}}\right)}}=\mathbb{K}. $$
   Is that definition correct? In what way is it equivalent to the other two conditions?

Comment: This is certainly not a definition intended for use in arbitrary categories!

Comment: What if we restrict to fusion or multifusion higher-categories so that the identity 1-morphism is the unit of fusion in the looping fusion $(n-1)$-category $\Omega\mathrm{End}(X) = \mathrm{End}(\mathrm{id}_X)$? And then repeat the looping until we end up with a 1-category?

Comment: Has anyone actually defined fusion n-categories?

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm not sure, but they are central in physics. For example, https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14178 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06663 use them.